# changing layout and activity in spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

First of all, I am fairly new at this, so bear with me.
I am trying to make a spinner where if you select an item, the layout and the activity will change, but I cant even implement the simplest of spinners.

so far the only code I've got is the one below, but no matter what I put in it doesn't do anything, so I must just not understand it, please be very specific in your answers. thank you. the first answer got me some of the way, but the "spinner spin..... spin.setAdapter(aa)" part is not accepted under OnCreate

```
String[] generations = { "Gen2", "Gen3", "Gen4", "Gen5", "Gen6","Gen7"  };

Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);  
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);  
ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,generations);  
aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
//Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner  
spin.setAdapter(aa);

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, gen2.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Gen3.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;
        case 3:
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, gen4.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
            break;
        case 4:
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, gen5.class);
            startActivity(intent5);
            break;
        case 5:
            Intent intent6 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent6);
            break;
        case 6:
            Intent intent7 = new Intent(this, gen7.class);
            startActivity(intent7);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example, hope it helps you understand it better:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

String[] country = { "India", "USA", "China", "Japan", "Other",  };

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
    //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on it  
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);  
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);  

    //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the country list  
    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,country);  
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
    //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner  
    spin.setAdapter(aa);  
}  


//Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected  
@Override  
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id) {  
    switch (position){
       // Check what position was selected 
       case 1:
       //start activity depending on position 
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityOne.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       break;

       case 2:
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       break;

       case 3:
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityThree.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       break;
}  

@Override  
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

}  

@Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);  
    return true;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: it got me closer, so thank you very much.
it still doesn't change anything really, it does not change the layout, it does not change the class